# Truffle - Error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx

Tags: solidity, truffle

```
truffle(development)> app.waterTree(0, {value: .0000000000001})
Error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 1188468318377797839569896498995073351059306341883237633081 and the sender's account only has: 99909466300000000000
```

I've tried two different functions and got the same result:

```
function waterTree(uint id) public payable {
    trees[id].ethValue += msg.value;
    //valueOfTree[id] += msg.value;
}
```

I have gas price set to 1 wei on Ganache and the gas limit is sitting at 7m.

Answer (score 1):

The value is in wei, not ether, so value must be an integer.